# VBA Macro to Close DDE Links

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am having trouble with DDE links in an Excel spreadsheet. It freezes up. I'm thinking it could be caused by an old DDE link and I have this script I'm trying to run to close all DDE links. Whenever I run it though I get,

Line:   2 
Char:   24
Error:  Expected end of statement
Code:   800A0401
Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error

Here is the code:

```
Sub KillDDE()
  Dim i, ChannelNumber As Integer
  For i = 1 To 1000
    Application.DDETerminate (i) ' Closes all DDE links whose channels might be open
    Next i
  ChannelNumber = Application.DDEInitiate("prortDDE", "DAX") 'initiates a new channel for a DDE link
  Range("A2").Value = Application.DDERequest(ChannelNumber, "Last")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that should help:

1. Use the `Application.DDETerminateAll` method [found HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171951%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
2. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197893%28v=office.15%29.aspx) `Application.DDEInitiate` returns a `Long` so `Dim ChannelNumber As Long`